# ASP.NET MVC Authentication Issues with internet explorer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

Log in/Log out isnt working, and uploading photos gives an error in internet explorer. Its working fine in firefox. We've already launched the site - and nobody has been able to enter the contest yet.

Heres the link:

[Url Removed]

Any help is appreciated. I can provide the code where requested.

*edit*
I don't know how else to describe the issue other than the default _LogOnPartial.cshtml file and the default Login/Logout actions in the AccountController.cs do not appear to work on this website hosted on IIS7. Running from localhost I can't recreate the issue. That domain is forwarded with masking to [Url Removed], but accessing that domain directly doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Please describe your issues in detail in here. Otherwise, the question will have no value for future generations once the problems are solved. Also, please specify in the tags what technologies and platforms you are using internally - .NET, PHP, Python...? (They all have MVC frameworks.) And do the problems you describe occur in IE only? Does it work in other browsers, and if so, which ones?

Comment: What error are you getting in Internet Explorer, a server error or a JavaScript error? Also, maybe provide an example login so we don't pollute your site with fake accounts

Comment: The issue only appears to be in internet explorer - we did all of our testing on firefox/chrome/safari before rushing to launch. We had a really short deadline.

Comment: The server is throwing an exception - "Object Reference not set to instance of an object". Feel free to make accounts - I can remove them easily - and a new account is required to upload an entry.

Comment: Weird. I don't know anything about ASP.NET but I expect you will need to show some code and/or a stack trace of the error

Comment: I cant get a stack trace, nor can I recreate the issue offline :(

Comment: @Gallen ah, that stinks. Anyway, error confirmed in IE8 with a RGB JPG image

Comment: Can you test logging in and logging out with the account you created?

Comment: @Gallen I can not log in. I get redirected to the registration page without change. I can log in in Chrome 10, though.

Comment: The fact your highlighting an issue in a certain browsers would suggest it has nothing to do with the .Net code but will be a javascript issue.

Comment: There's no java script issue - It's a cookie issue with internet explorer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, the issue is now resolved - It was due to the forwarding with masking affecting the way internet explorer was handling forms. We purchased a dedicated domain for the contest and can now log in and out without issue as well as upload photos without that error. This was a very odd problem.